# Add zeros to String in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, realloc

I want to add zeroes in front of a string with this method:

```
void addFrontzeros(char *str,int zeros)
{
    if(zeros==0)
    {
        return;
    }

    char *temp=malloc((strlen(str)+1+zeros)*sizeof(char));

    int i=0;
    for(;i<zeros;i++)
    {
        temp[i]='0';
    }

    int j=0;
    for(;j<strlen(str);j++)
    {
        temp[j+zeros]=str[j];
    }
    temp[strlen(str)+zeros]=0;
    str=realloc(str,(strlen(temp)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(str,temp);
    free(temp);
}
```

But when i call it from another Method the string is empty after the invocation.
The caller string is allocated like this in another method:

```
char *mul = malloc(sizeof(char)*2);
    mul[0]='0';
    mul[1]=0;
```

With valgrind i got this error:
Address 0x5201b00 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 2 free'd

I think the problem is with realloc , but i don't have an idea why it wont work here

Comment: You're loosing pointer returned by `realloc` after leaving the function (as it is assigned to local pointer), plus you do not set null terminator in the second loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By calling `realloc` you're (possibly) modifying `str` inside the function, but the caller of `addFrontzeros` doesn't see the new value of `str`. It still has the old version of `str` which no longer points to valid data after the `realloc`.

Your function should either `return str` (so that it can be called as `x = addFrontzeros(x, n)`) or accept a `char **` so that it can modify the pointer in place.

As pointed out by StoryTeller, `str = realloc(str, ...)` is unsafe in the case where `realloc` fails. First, because you're not testing whether `realloc` returned `NULL`, and second, because if it *does* return `NULL`, you have a memory leak because the old `str` is still allocated but you've lost your pointer to it. A minimal way to handle it would be

```
char *new_str = realloc(str, strlen(temp)+1);
if (!new_str) {
    perror("addFrontzeros: realloc");
} else {
    str = new_str;
}
```

although if you want to handle the failure in some other way, you can, and the original `str` will still be valid and unmodified.

Another problem is that you only copy `strlen(str)` bytes, which doesn't include the terminating zero byte, so your string is not correctly terminated. Either add the terminating zero yourself, or simply copy one more byte (since you can assume `str` *is* correctly terminated to start with).

Finally, as a side note, `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so multiplying by it is unnecessary.

Comment: Assigning the result of `realloc` blindly to the existing pointer is also unsafe.

Comment: @StoryTeller that's because on failure it will return `NULL` but not modify the existing memory, so a blind reassignment causes a leak, correct?

Comment: Yup, that's what I had in mind. Seeing as a failure to reallocate may not necessarily mean your program is toast (say if `zeros` is huge). A failure in the function shouldn't modify `str`.

Comment: @StoryTeller okay, I added some advice in that direction. Trying not to get too long-winded. :)

Comment: thank you , i changed it now to get the pointer returned , now it works